# Get guests Google Calendar updates to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

So here's what I am trying to do.

1. Get my Google Calendar Events Data to my spreadsheet
2. Get all my guests calendar updates of the same in the same sheet, so I know how many are coming, how many would be maybe and how many rejected.

I am able to do the First requirement, not sure how to go ahead with second one.

**More update:**
More like, I will have weekend events for a bunch of people in my group, and I will be sending them invites for the same. Now in my spreadsheets I want to see at once everyone's response. Also to get an idea, how many are free for the following weekends, and how many are busy. Can this be done?

Comment: You can do this. Here's a link in the documentation to get you started. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest

Comment: I am able to get my own calendar details. But getting guests status and their calendar details is what I am stuck with.